# Flask App - Local Development Environment - changes not reflecting

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, development-environment

I have a Flask App that I am running locally and testing. Every time, I make a change in the Application code, the changes would reflect on the dev environment `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` with a simple browser refresh.

Now, I have to terminate the Flask App `Ctrl X` + `Ctrl C` and then reboot / relaunch the App. I am using `gunicorn` to launch the Flask App.

Not sure what changed, but how do I configure the App such that the changes take effect on refresh?

I have the following line of code in `init.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 80, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

Comment: when running your app did you set debug = true? 
`app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: @bro no - i just use `gunicorn dir:file`

Comment: @bro I have `use_debugger=True` in run_simple. Please see the code in the post.

Comment: I find it uncommon to use `gunicorn` in development environment.

Answer (score 10):

Gunicorn has its own system to reload the worker process when the application code changes. You can use the [`--reload` CLI flag](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload) to activate the auto-reloading dev mode.

```
gunicorn --reload app:app
```

You can add additional files to the watcher via the [`--reload-extra-file FILES`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload-extra-files) arg.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also using Gunicorn

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```